# Type Cast with custom object ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, casting

I have an array that may have objects of "Theme" class or "Language" class. Now I am Type Casting my method to Theme class manually. I want to check If array have objects of Theme class then Type cast it with Theme

```
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[(Theme *)[_listArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] name]];
```

_listArray may also objects of Language Class.

I have done

```
Class theClass  = [[_listArray firstObject] class];

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[(theClass *)[_listArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] name]];
```

But it is not working...!!! 
How should I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it is not necessary to type cast `id` objects stored in `NSArray` to a specific type before sending it the message `name`. This will compile as well:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[_listArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] name]];
```

However, you would get a run-time problem if the corresponding element does not respond to selector `name`. Here is how:

```
NSObject *item = [_listArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
if ([item respondsToSelector:@selector(name)]) {
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[item name]];
}
```